# 500 Error with AT&T/ ATT Speech to text API Python

Tags: python, curl, raspberry-pi, voice-recognition, att

I am trying to record a wav file using Arecord in order to upload to the AT&T speech to text, the problem is I am only recieving a 500 error as shown below. does anyone know how to fix this ?

I have utilized the following class & SH files from this page:
http://changingjasper.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/making-jasper-use-at-speech-api.html

here is my python file:

```
   #from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
    from ATTSpeech import ATTSpeech
    from os import system
    from json import loads
    import traceback
    import sys
    def runCommand():
        system("arecord -D plughw:1 -t wav -d 4 -r 8000 -f cd temp.wav")

    def deleteTemp():
        system("rm ./temp.wav")        


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        attEngine = ATTSpeech()
        try:
            runCommand()
            #phrase, response = speech_to_text()
        result = attEngine.getResults("./temp.wav")
        print result
            deleteTemp()
            #print phrase
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print "error keyboard interrupted"
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
       # sys.exit(0)
            print "error exception" 
        #runCommand()
        #phrase, response = speech_to_text()
        #deleteTemp()
        #print phrase
```

the class file is the following, (I have removed my credentials for security reasons):

```
import subprocess
import urllib2
from subprocess import call

class ATTSpeech:
    CLIENT_ID = "**********************************"
    CLIENT_SECRET = "*********************************"
    TOKEN = "None"
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def getToken(self):
        #Get Access Token via OAuth.
        proc = subprocess.Popen(["/var/www/att/getToken.sh", self.CLIENT_ID, self.CLIENT_SECRET], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        tmp = proc.stdout.read()
        tmp = tmp.replace("\"","").replace("{","").replace("}","").split(":")[1]
        self.TOKEN = tmp[:32]

    def getResults(self,path):
        if not self.haveInternet():
            return ["SPECIAL CASE I COULD NOT CONNECT TO THE INTERNET",None]

        proc = subprocess.Popen(["sh","/var/www/att/getResults.sh",self.TOKEN,path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        tmp = proc.stdout.read()
        for strin in tmp.upper().replace("\"","").replace("{","").replace("[","").replace(":","").replace("}","").replace("]","").split(","):
            print strin
            if "HYPOTHESIS" in strin:
                strin = strin.strip().replace("HYPOTHESIS","").strip()
                return [strin,None]
            if "IOEXCEPTION" in strin:
                return ["SPECIAL CASE SPEECH API HAD AN ERROR",None]
            if "UNAUTHORIZED" in strin:
                print "The current token is invalic, getting a new one..."
                self.getToken()
                return self.getResults(path)
        return ["",""]

    def haveInternet(self):
        try:
            response=urllib2.urlopen('http://74.125.228.100',timeout=1) #Google IP. Prevents a long DNS look up for a url. 1 second timeout. Adjust as needed
            return True
        except urllib2.URLError as err: pass
        return False
```

the sh files which contain the curl are as follows:

getToken.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
curl "https://api.att.com/oauth/token" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    --header "Accept: application/json" \
    --data "client_id=$1&client_secret=$2&scope=SPEECH&grant_type=client_credentials" \
    --request POST
```

getResults.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
curl "https://api.att.com/speech/v3/speechToText"  \
        --header "Authorization: Bearer $1" \
        --header "Accept: application/json" \
        --header "Content-Type: audio/wav" \
        --data-binary @$2 \
        --request POST
```

I recieve the following error:

ERRORHTTPCODE500
HTTPRESPONSEMESSAGEINTERNAL SERVER ERROR
ERRORTYPESPEECHENGINEEXCEPTION
ERRORMESSAGEIOEXCEPTION OCCURRED WHILE CALLING WATSON ASR SERVICE.
['SPECIAL CASE SPEECH API HAD AN ERROR', None]

If anyone could help me with this problem I would be very grateful.

Comment: 500 error usually means something on the server side, I doubt there is anything you can do from your client. If it was a problem with your request, you would be getting a 4xx error code.

Comment: Yeah, That's what I assumed. I thought possibly the file encoding might be triggering it possibly, as I'm using their API's official Curl scripts.